# APD temperature variation

Tags: temperature, compensation, photosensor

I know that the gain (M factor) of APD (Avalance Photo Diode) changes with temperature at a give reverse bias voltage, therefore, we need to a compensation either using a thermoelectric cooler or a reverse bias control circuit. As far as I know, there are two sources of heat, one is ambient temperature fluctuation (couple of degrees) and another is heat source due to heat dissipation in APD junction (which dependent on signal as well as reverse dark current). My question is, which one is the major source of gain fluctuation in APD?

Comment: APD meaning????

Comment: APD power from VI product may be highest depending on applied photon current and thermal resistance 'C/W or ambient depending on location

Comment: In my experience ambient temperature changes dominate since I usually have short pulses of light incident on the APD generating short pulses of current.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about APD's.  But in general a temperature change is a temperature change (regardless of where it comes from.)  So 1 degree change in ambient will be about the same as 1 degree change due to power dissipation in the ADP.